# insert data to table using connector/Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a table with 4 columns id (which is primary and auto increment), name,branch and total_marks. I followed the connector/Python documentation and came up with the following code:

```
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                              password ='root',
                              host='localhost:8889',
                              database='testdb')

cur = con.cursor()

add_student = ("INSERT INTO student "
               "(name, branch, total_marks) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

data_student = ('John','Computer Science',1697)

#insert new student details

cur.execute(add_student,data_student)

con.commit()

cur.close()
con.close()
```

However on running it on the terminal nothing happens,apparently. It doesn't show any error,in fact I have to exit using ctrl-Z. What could be the problem?

Comment: What are you expecting to be happening? You should do a `SELECT` query and see if the new data is in the DB.

Comment: well i checked the table..nothing gets inserted but when i do it through MAMP it works..so something must be wrong in the script no? i'll try the select bit too though. thanks. @DeepSpace

Comment: same thing happens on trying do a SELECT query.